# How does cumulative acknowledgement mechanism allows for straight-forward duplicate detection in case of retransmission?

Tags: tcp

I'm reading the RFC 793.

https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc793.txt

```
The acknowledgment mechanism employed is cumulative so that an acknowledgment of sequence
  number X indicates that all octets up to but not including X have been
  received.  This mechanism allows for straight-forward duplicate
  detection in the presence of retransmission.
```

I am stuck here. I am wondering how is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to read the whole section - the current version of TCP is in [RFC 9293](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9293) (**emphasis** mine):

> ### 3.4. Sequence Numbers
>
> A fundamental notion in the design is that **every octet of data sent
> over a TCP connection has a sequence number**. Since every octet is
> sequenced, each of them can be acknowledged. The acknowledgment
> mechanism employed is cumulative so that an acknowledgment of sequence
> number X indicates that all octets up to but not including X have been
> received. **This mechanism allows for straightforward duplicate
> detection** in the presence of retransmission.

"This mechanism" refers to the sequence numbering, not necessarily to cumulative acknowledgement. Without sequence numbers, you'd be hard pressed to detect duplicate transmissions.

Comment: I see, so when a packet arrives that contains the same sequence number as the another received segment, the destination TCP simply discards the packet.